# LVM filter does not stop when rule matches?

Tags: linux, lvm, regex, filter

I have a problem with a lvm filter configuration.
I want to filter out certain devices/partitions from lvm scan. I can do it by making filter like so:

```python
filter = ["a|/dev/disk/by-partuuid/<uuid>|", "r|.*|"]
```

This will only scan given partition and skip any other device but for me this is pain in the a.
This means every time I add new partition/disk (most of the time i setup lvm resource there) I have to remember and manually change lvm filter to accept that new device.

I have thought that it would work the other way around - reject selected devices and accept any other device in lvm filter.

```python
filter = ["r|/dev/disk/by-partuuid/<uuid>|", "a|.*|"]
```

But it looks like the lvm does not stop on first filter rule that does match, it goes onward and at the end is accept all rule.

Funny thing, it looks like setting filter like so:

```python
filter = ["r|/dev/disk/by-partuuid/<uuid>|"]
```

Actually works the way I want and scans devices not excluded in the filter.

But I wonder why? Should it work with the second example that way?
And why it works anyway if I do not provide any `include` rules in the filter?